# LINQ join using Generics

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to write LINQ join query In generics, but having trouble in identifying the Foreign Key. PFB code.

I want to identify the Foreign Key present in table U, which I can use it for the comparison operation.Thanks

```
var _tab = (from tblT in context.GetTable<T>()
            join tblU in context.GetTable<U>()
            on pk equals fk 
            select tblT).GetEnumerator();
```

Comment: Unclear question

Comment: What are you using? LINQ to SQL? Entity framework?

Comment: @mahditahsildari : is it clear? new to stackoverflow, having trouble in formatting... :(

Comment: Your problem description is "having trouble in identifying the Foreign Key". That's not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have improved **@Gary.S** answer. here I improved regarding query selector and how to use where close in here. I think this will help full for you.

this is the **generic method** which I updated.

Note : **AppDbContext  is my dbContext**

```
public class MyGenMetClass
{
    public async Task<IEnumerable<TResult>> FetchJonBy<TOuter, TInner, TKey, TResult>(Expression<Func<TOuter, TKey>> outerKeySelector, Expression<Func<TInner, TKey>> innerKeySelector, Expression<Func<TOuter, bool>> wherOuter, Expression<Func<TInner, bool>> wherInner, Expression<Func<TOuter, TInner, TResult>> resultSelector) where TOuter : class where TInner : class where TResult : class
     {
       try
       {
           using (AppDbContext db = new AppDbContext())
           {
                var data = await db.Set<TOuter>().Where(wherOuter).Join(db.Set<TInner>().Where(wherInner), outerKeySelector, innerKeySelector, resultSelector).ToListAsync();
                    return data;
            }
       }catch (Exception ex){
            return null;
       }
   }
}
```

and my model like this.

**SupplierModel** Class

```
public class SupplierModel
{
        [Key]
        public int SupplierId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

**SupplierCatgory** Class

```
public class SupplierCatgory
{
       [Key]
       public int CategoryId { get; set; }
       public string Category { get; set; }        
       public Boolean IsActive { get; set; } = true;  
}
```

**SupplierViewModel** Class

```
public class SupplierViewModel
{       
        public int SupplierId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

here I *joined* **SupplierModel** and **SupplierCatgory** and *return* **SupplierViewModel**

And you can call like this

```
var result =await new MyGenMetClass().FetchJonBy<SupplierModel,SupplierCatgory,int, SupplierViewModel>(s=> s.CategoryId,c=>c.CategoryId ,m=>m.IsAcvtive==true,c=>c.IsActive==true, (s, y) => new SupplierViewModel() { Name=s.Name,Category=y.Category} );
```

Comment: What's wrong with the regular `Join` method? (Even the original answer doesn't add much). Your method is needlessly complex, esp. these where clauses are more of a nuisance than that they're helpful.

Comment: I agreed this is bit complex. but you can return Viewmodel (customized model) instead of return single model as a list using this. also you can use where clues to filter data.

Comment: *also you can use where clues to filter data* -- Yeah, but you cannot *not* use them and that covers 99% of the use cases for joins. And just the regular `Join` also returns any view model if desired.

Comment: And I didn't even mention that returning the `IQueryable` as `IEnumerable` blocks a consumer of this method to compose on the result. (also applies to the original).

Answer (score 6):

You mention that you want to "identify the Foreign Key present in table U". While you may be able to do that via reflection and some sort of convention it seems like it would be a brittle solution. I would suggest that you provide the primary/foreign key relationship via a delegate.

Basically a join uses a delegate for retrieving the primary and foreign keys and the LINQ provider translates that into the join clause. The signature of each side of the join is basically the same, in your example it would be: `Expression<Func<T, TKey>>` and `Expression<Func<U, TKey>>`. It is important to note the the key type must be the same for both sides of the join.

Whatever you use to call this method should require that these delegates be passed in. It might look something like this:

```
public class Query
{
    public IEnumerable<T> GetData<T, U, TKey>(Expression<Func<T, TKey>> tKey, Expression<Func<U, TKey>> uKey)
    {
        Context context = new Context();
        // using the extension method as the query expression had trouble figuring out the types
        var data = context.GetTable<T>().Join(context.GetTable<U>(), tKey, uKey, (tblT, tblU) => tblT);            

        return data;
    }
}
```

Calling it would look like this:

```
var data = query.GetData<Person, Order, int>(person => person.Id, order => order.Orderer.Id);
```

Comment: Brilliant solution for what I was looking for, Thank you.